# Force Excel to run macro using SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, xlsm

I have a requirement to run the Excel file (either .xls or .xlsm) which has macros in it and it reduces the size of the other excel file and save it as different file in same folder. It works fine when I open the file manually from the folder, it runs immediately and creates the shrinked file.

But the requirement is to open the Excel from SQL query and run it. I am trying to do it with these two ways in my SQL query.

```
(1) EXEC [master].dbo.xp_cmdshell 'c:\temp\MyExcelShrink.xls'
(2) EXEC  xp_cmdshell  'dtexec /f c:\temp\MyPackage.dtsx'
```

The dtsx package has the same logic to open the Excel and run it, but none of these code working.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Why are you trying to open an excel file with a query? The database is managing and storing data, it is not a programming language. This sounds like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: I agree with @SeanLange (which isn't unusual) - what is the "big picture" goal that you're trying to accomplish?  My first guess is that you want to run this Excel file on a schedule - if so, there are alternatives to SQL Server that better suit that task.

Comment: It 's kind of a calculative query. Which at the end shrinks the different sheets from one file and merges into a single sheet and save it as a separate excel file, but the strange thing is it is saving with ".xlsm" extension.  This is an existing logic created by someone, I'm trying to fix it.

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic712359-149-1.aspx
You can probably do what you want to do with SSIS and a Script Task.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks @digital.aaron, but the code is pretty old and throwing lot of errors. Also the current logic to open the excel file is this:

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\myExcel.xlsm");

Seems like, its just trying to run the macros without opening the file, but its not working. As soon as I open the file manually, the macros run and they do their logic for copying the file and saving the file with different name.

Comment: You still haven't explained why part of the requirement is "open the Excel __*from SQL query*__.  Why must it be done "from SQL query"?

Answer (score 0):

When you use xp_cmdshell, the process that starts runs in the security context of the SQL Server service login. That account may not have desktop interactivity enabled or may lack other permissions that Excel requires to run macros at start-up.

See [this xp_cmdshell article on the SQL Server Security Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2008/01/10/xp_cmdshell/) for more information about xp_cmdshell, including a recommendation that it shouldn't be used: "Generally speaking, you must avoid using xp_cmdshell, and if possible, you should remove any dependency on it."