# SSIS Macro not able to open Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have following code to open the excel file.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("c:\\Temp\\MyExcel.xls"); // absolute path needed
Thread.Sleep(30000);
xlApp.Quit();
```

If I place this code in any code file using website or window application it runs fine, it also opens my excel file which automatically runs macros and complete the logic in it.

But when I put the same code in SSIS and try to run the code, it doesn't work.

Can anyone please guide me further in this? It is getting critical.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it throw an error?

Comment: How is this different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52767071/force-excel-to-run-macro-using-sql-query?

Comment: Hi @Brian, the post which you mentioned was using the way to call the logic either to open and excel directly or through an SSIS. This post is for the code withing SSIS to open excel and run macros immediately.

Comment: @digital.aaron: no, it says it runs successfully, but it doesn't actually run the macros inside the excel.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with executing macros inside an Execl file programatically, but it seems like maybe you need to specifically invoke the macros. Check out the example here: https://programmingeveryday.wordpress.com/2013/02/20/run-excel-macro-programmatically-in-c/

Comment: @digital.aaron: Yes, Aaron it looks like the same to me and I am trying it. The only thing which I feel weird is the same code which I mentioned in the post, if I run through a window or web application, it does it successfully, but if I run the same code in SSIS, it doesn't run.

Comment: Are you running SSIS in Visual Studio (debug) or is it deployed to an SSIS server? I have a feeling that the issue involves security context. If you're running under VS, the security context will be your account and Excel's Trust settings will respond accordingly. When deployed, the security context will be the account SQL Server/SSIS is running under and the Excel Trust Center settings may not be satisfied to where your startup macro will run.

Comment: This still smells like [an XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).